# Is there an R function that converts dates from integer to actual dates?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I am trying to execute the following command for mutating a new column. If the Lease.End.date is blank it should be replaced by Distribution date else Lease.End.Date.

I am getting incorrect values for correctdate column

```
newdata <- data %>% select(FI, Lease.End.Date, Distribution.Date) %>% mutate(correctdate = ifelse(Lease.End.Date == "", 
                                                Distribution.Date,Lease.End.Date))
> typeof(newdata$correctdate)
[1] "integer"
> typeof(newdata$Lease.End.Date)
[1] "integer"
> typeof(newdata$Distribution.Date)
[1] "integer"  

> data

       FI Lease.End.Date Distribution.Date
1       3      31-Jul-25         13-Aug-19
2       3                        13-Aug-19
3       3                        13-Aug-19
4       3      31-Jan-19         13-Aug-19
5       3      31-Jan-24         13-Aug-19
6       3      13-Aug-20         13-Aug-19
7       3      13-Aug-21         13-Aug-19
8       3      13-Aug-22         13-Aug-19
9       3      13-Aug-23         13-Aug-19
10      3      13-Aug-24         13-Aug-19

> newdata
       FI Lease.End.Date Distribution.Date correctdate
1       3      31-Jul-25         13-Aug-19          34
2       3                        13-Aug-19           1
3       3                        13-Aug-19           1
4       3      31-Jan-19         13-Aug-19          27
5       3      31-Jan-24         13-Aug-19          31
6       3      13-Aug-20         13-Aug-19           7
7       3      13-Aug-21         13-Aug-19           8
8       3      13-Aug-22         13-Aug-19           9
9       3      13-Aug-23         13-Aug-19          10  


I want the correctdate column should have following values:

31-Jul-25
13-Aug-19
13-Aug-19
31-Jan-19
.
.
.
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem you have. You date print fine to the console.

Comment: can you post the output of `dput(newdata)`?

Comment: `Lease.End.Date` and `Distribution.Date` are `factor` vectors. Their type is `integer`, but they actually are encoding of a string. What's the output of `class(newdata$Distribution.Date)`? See `?factor` to know what a `factor` is and check the `stringsAsFactors` argument of `read.table` and its related functions.

Comment: ```class(newdata$Distribution.Date)``` is ```factor```

Comment: ```dput(newdata)``` has the output ```structure(list(FI = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,.....), Lease.End.Date = structure(c(34L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 31L, 7L, 8L, 9L...), Distribution.Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L....), .Label = c("13-Aug-19", "16-Aug-19"), class = "factor"), correctdate = c(34L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 31L, 7L, 8L, 9L...) ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -70L))```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(FI = c(3,3,3, 3,3), Lease.End.Date = c("31-Jul-25", "", "", "31-Jan-19", "31-Jan-24"), Distribution.Date = c("13-Aug-19", "13-Aug-19", "13-Aug-19", "13-Aug-19", "13-Aug-19"))

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
typeof(data$Lease.End.Date)                                                                             
#[1] "integer"
class(data$Lease.End.Date)
#[1] "factor"

typeof(data$Distribution.Date)                                               
#"integer"
class(data$Distribution.Date)                                               
#[1] "factor"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# format the columns as date using lubridate date functions
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

data$Distribution.Date <- dmy(data$Distribution.Date)

data$Lease.End.Date <- dmy(data$Lease.End.Date)

class(data$Distribution.Date)
#[1] "Date"
class(data$Lease.End.Date) 
#[1] "Date"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# the ifelse
newdata <- data %>% 
  select(FI, Lease.End.Date, Distribution.Date) %>% 
  mutate(correctdate = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(Lease.End.Date) ,Distribution.Date, Lease.End.Date), origin="1970-01-01")) 
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# newdata
#   FI Lease.End.Date Distribution.Date correctdate
# 1  3     2025-07-31        2019-08-13  2025-07-31
# 2  3           <NA>        2019-08-13  2019-08-13
# 3  3           <NA>        2019-08-13  2019-08-13
# 4  3     2019-01-31        2019-08-13  2019-01-31
# 5  3     2024-01-31        2019-08-13  2024-01-31
```